# Windows 2003 subdomain not working

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, subdomain

I'm trying to add a subdomain to my main one, to be connected to an external IP address.

So I have:
example.com
mail.example.com
www.example.com

Which are working.

I want to add test.example.com bound to an external IP address (1.10.100.200).
I was going to forward lookup zones, example.com ; I have added there an A-record with test and IP address 1.10.100.200. 
It is successfully added but nothing happens.
test.example.com is not resolved at all.

Did I do this correctly or does it need something else ?

Answer (score 0):

A record of "test" seems to be correctly added. Try to flush the DNS caching and have a check.

---

No, just allow some time and your sub-domain will be accessible through Internet.

Comment: Thanks, that appeared to have solved it partially, I get ICMP response from the correct IP address when pinging test.maindomain.com, however it only works internally. Anything else is needed for this to work externally (from the internet) ?

Comment: It's been a few days and the new name only works internally, but not on the internet. Anything I should check ?

Comment: Share your subdomain name and the result of dig for both main domain and subdomain.